# print all users list in android app using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I am working on printing all users based on the UID, but I only get one user printed.
This is the result I am getting now.
[image]

Here is what the printingUserList(), this is a small function to retrieve all user information based on UID.

```
RecyclerView rv;
UserAdapter usrAdapter;
ArrayList<User> mUsrsList;

private void readUsrs(){
        LinearLayoutManager LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
        mUsrsList = new ArrayList<>();

        final FirebaseUser me = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mUsrsList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("TAG_", "A++" + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()); //prints 5, which exactly has five users in the database.
                    User all_usr = ds.getValue(User.class);
                    if (!all_usr.getUid().equals(me.getUid())) { //won't print itself
                        mUsrsList.add(all_usr);
                    }

                }
                System.out.println(mUsrsList.toString());
                usrAdapter = new UserAdapter(RoomUser_Activity.this, mUsrsList);
                rv.setAdapter(usrAdapter);
                usrAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
        });
    }
```

and this is the recyclerview, should be correct otherwise it prints nothing

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
    private Context m_context;
    private ArrayList<User> all_users;
    public static final String EXTRA_HISUID = "NoHisUID";
    public UserAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> all_users) {
        this.m_context = context;
        this.all_users = all_users;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserAdapter.UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(m_context);
        View itemv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_item_user, parent, false); //xml provide below
        return new UserViewHolder(itemv);
    }


    public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public ImageView UserIcon; //default icon provided in xml
        public TextView Username;

        public UserViewHolder (View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            UserIcon = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.usr_icon);
            Username = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_username);
        }
    }


    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserAdapter.UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
        User usr = all_users.get(position);
        final String hisUID = usr.getUid();
        holder.Username.setText(usr.getUsername());
        if(usr.getIcon().equals("default_icon")){
            holder.UserIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_icon);
        }
        else{
            Glide.with(m_context).load(usr.getIcon()).into(holder.UserIcon);
        }
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return all_users.size();
    }
```

layout_item_user.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/usr_icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/usr_icon"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/usr_icon"
        android:text="username"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lastMessageTv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="The last message"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/usr_icon"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_username"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

database:

```
users: 
|-2NUPkQuHFRS49ZHDZzEtWiErIiv1
  |-address: "920 West 4th Ave apt231"
  |-city: "blank"
  |-donut: 0
  |-email: "not_busy@gmail.com"
  |-full_name: "blank"
  |-icon: "default_icon"
  |-phone: "253353309"
  |-state: "blank"
  |-uid: "2NUPkQuHFRS49ZHDZzEtWiErIiv1"
  |-username: "not_busy" 
|-F0NRthr8uJPYMz2o129w2PAf30i1
|-GRJPA5hKA6aRgNl68sSxv3xruww1
|-W0PIUjUwRHXTkooztYFuhKuLItE3
|-cBzUNHceM2T47cr0zWX1tqgB2wA3
```

It must be a small bug, but I still cannot figure what problem is.. thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean here  `if (!all_usr.getUid().equals(me.getUid())) { //won't print itself`? wont print itself

Comment: it will print your account itself, because I am making a chat room

Comment: so you are adding only one account inside the arrayList? Also log `all_usr`

Comment: This DataSnapshot should have five times for loop, Log all_usr inside the for loop gives me 5 log prints users ID.

Comment: remove the if and tell me what you get in the arrayLsit

Comment: mUsrsList.add(all_usr); should be cumulative, but it only get the first one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203511/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-zion-hin-wong).